# Analyzing query statistics in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, optimization, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to analyze my MySql database and server and when looking in phpmyadmin Status->Query statistics I can see that these three queries are the most used:

```
set option 31.91%
change db 15.71%
show variables 15.83%
```

I'm quite a newbie in MySql and my question is now: Why are these queries running so often? SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE are not at all that frequently running on the server. I just wanted to see if this is normal behavior?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on the amount that you use phpMyAdmin vs running actual queries.  My guess is that `set option`, `change db`, and `show variables` are used pretty often by phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I just started up phpMyAdmin now, so I don't think it is that. I have lots of users connected to the database, but can't see why they would run things like set option, change db...?

Comment: @Martin It makes sense that phpMyAdmin would be using those queries -- setting options for the current session and then switching to the appropriate database.